# Random walk on non-negative integers - Transcience Recurrence etc

Tags: markov-chains

Good evening. I have a problem concerning the random walk on non-negative integers. Suppose that $ p_{0,1}=1 , p_{i,i+1}=1-p , p_{i,i-1}=p $ . I would like to know for which value of $ p $ this random walk is transient/recurrent. I tried to apply the classical theorem about calculating the probabilities $ p_{0,0}^{(2n)} $ and then try to tell if the series over $ n $ converges, but it seems really hard to find an explicit formula about these n-th transition probabilities.
Does anybody have any idea about this?

Comment: This is asked before on some link.  But a simple start is to assume you are in a state $i>0$ and define $q$ as the probability that you ever (eventually) reach a point to your left (i.e., $i-1$).  You can write a quadratic equation for $q$ in terms of $p$ by simply considering the two possibilities associated with the first step.

Comment: You mean to define $ T_{i-1}= \inf \{ j \geq 1 : X_j = i-1 \} $ and then calculate $ P [ T_{i-1} < \infty | X_0 = i ] $ by conditioning on the first step ??

Comment: Yes.  You will notice that $T_i$ and $T_{i+1}$ have the same distribution for $i \geq 1$.